# MongoDB search in nested documents with dynamic keys?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "582b5fdf09ecd804b275894c"
  },
  "scriptData": {
    "playerStats": {
      "582b5f9409ecd804b2752bc7": {
        "status": "closed",
        "tileSum": "0"
      },
      "582b6082d20c9404b29d4d6f": {
        "status": "closed",
        "tileSum": "16"
      }
    }
  },
  "startDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1479237815109"
    }
  },
  "nextPlayer": "582b6082d20c9404b29d4d6f"
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to find every document where tileSum is greater thank 200, but have not been successful. The keys in playerStats are dynamic. It is the players ID.

I have tried like this:

```
db.collection.find({
       "scriptData":{
          "playerStats":{
             "tileSum":{
                "$gt":200
             }
          }
       }
    })
```

But I get this error: The action could not be executed. Please check your parameters.

I am not sure how to accomplish this and hoping for help...

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Your keys are dynamic here inside the `playerStats`?

Comment: Yes, they are dynamics. It is the players id.

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside a Program? Or Mongo Shell?

Comment: Looks like you're using nested documents instead of an array. I see only nested objects.

Comment: @Richang Sharma - It is in GameSparks backend data explorer I am running this.

Comment: @Astro - Actually, you are correct. It is nested documents... How do I solve this though?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to wrap the playerStats in an array and then use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to compare within an array:

**Data:**

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "582b5fdf09ecd804b275894c"
    },
    "scriptData": {
      "playerStats": [
        {
          "id": "582b5f9409ecd804b2752bc7",
          "status": "closed",
          "tileSum": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "582b6082d20c9404b29d4d6f",
          "status": "closed",
          "tileSum": "16"
        }
      ]
    },
    "startDate": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1479237815109"
      }
    },
    "nextPlayer": "582b6082d20c9404b29d4d6f"
  }
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$scriptData.playerStats",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$item.tileSum",
              "16"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("582b5fdf09ecd804b275894c"),
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "582b6082d20c9404b29d4d6f",
        "status": "closed",
        "tileSum": "16"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the exact same issue, but I wasn't in a place where I can change my data model/data format. So after a lot of research, documentation reading and logic I came up with this solution that should work.

Writing it here so any other developer who comes across the same issue gets a solution.

I created an aggregation like follows:

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      all: {
        $objectToArray: "$scriptData.playerStats",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$all",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "all.v.tileSum": { $gte: 200 },
    },
  },
];
```

This will give you your desired data I believe.

It works step by step as the following image:

[image: mongo description]